# HighCharts XY Scatter Plot Color Gradient

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I have a HighCharts XY Plot where I'm plotting the X & Y coordinates of a point across the axes which I obtain from an api which returns values at a 5 second interval. We also have a history api that returns the value of the points in a given interval.

My question is can we create a color gradient for the points based on the time received?

For example, I have 5 points with x,y coordinates
2,2 at 10.20am

1,3 at 10.21am

3,2 at 10.22am

1,2 at 10.23am

2,3 at 10.24am

And i apply green color to them.

So 2,3 will be the brightest & 2,2 will be almost washed out

Can we do this using HighCharts?

Comment: yes you can do this using HighChart. Please give it a try and come back if you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the gradient using `colorAxis` and setting `series.colorKey` to `x` to achieve the horizontal gradient.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter'
  },
  colorAxis: [{
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    minColor: '#FF0000',
    maxXolor: '#0000FF'
  }],
  series: [{
    colorKey: 'x',
    data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
  }]
});
```

Example demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s5thxgj3/
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9z4rkshm/